# Second hover transition for scale on <img> tag not working correctly

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform

I am trying to make two different `:hover` effects for a parent and its child.

HTML

```
<section class="col large-poster">
               <div class="image-area">
                      <img class="img-cover" src="/path.png" alt="Maven" />
                </div>
                <div class="poster-cover">
                     <div>
                         <h1>
                            Item 
                          </h1>
                     </div>
                </div>
 </section>
```

OPACITY TRANSITION

I am changing the opacity to `1` using this:

```
main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster > .image-area {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            opacity: .265;
            transition: 4s ease;
}

      main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster:hover > .image-area {
            opacity: 1;
     }
```

This works fine, but I wish to be able to scale it slowly as well, my CSS doesn't seem to work for `:hover` scale. It is built on the same logic as the opacity fade.

SCALE TRANSITION

```
main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster > .image-area > img {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: -752px;
        width: auto;
        /* height: auto */
        height: 1000px;
        transform:scale(1,1);
        transition: 8s all;
    }

   main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster:hover > image-area > img {
      transform:scale(1.2,1.2)
   }
```

---

[jdFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/9a10p7n0/4/)

---

```css
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container:after, .group:before, .group:after, .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .row:before, .row:after {
    content: '\0020';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.container:after, .row:after, .clearfix:after, .group:after {
    clear: both;
}

.row, .clearfix, .group {
    zoom: 1;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background: #fff
}

img:not(.img-cover),
svg {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto
}

.col {
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
    display:block
}

main {
    display: block;
    background: black
}

    main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster {
        min-height: 892px;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

        main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster > .image-area {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            opacity: .265;
            transition: 4s ease;
        }

        main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster:hover > .image-area {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster > .image-area > img {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-left: -752px;
            width: auto;
            /* height: auto */
            height: 1000px;
            transform:scale(1,1);
            transition: 8s all;
        }

        main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster:hover > image-area > img {
            transform:scale(1.2,1.2)
        }

        main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster > .poster-cover {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
        }

            main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster > .poster-cover > div {
                margin: 0 40px;
                text-align: center
            }

                main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster > .poster-cover > div > h1 {
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    color: #fff;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    font-size: 2.455rem;
                    line-height: 1.2;
                }
```

```html
    <main id="wrap">
        <div class="page">
           <div class="group">
               <section class="col large-poster">
                        <div class="image-area">
                              <img class="img-cover" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/k15SYSI.jpg" alt="Maven" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="poster-cover">
                            <div>
                                <h1>
                                    First 
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
               </section>
               <section class="col large-poster">
                        <div class="image-area">
                              <img class="img-cover" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/k15SYSI.jpg" alt="Maven" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="poster-cover">
                            <div>
                                <h1>
                                    Second Item 
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
               </section>
               <section class="col large-poster">
                        <div class="image-area">
                              <img class="img-cover" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/k15SYSI.jpg" alt="Maven" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="poster-cover">
                            <div>
                                <h1>
                                    Third Item
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
               </section>
               <section class="col large-poster">
                        <div class="image-area">
                              <img class="img-cover" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/k15SYSI.jpg" alt="Maven" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="poster-cover">
                            <div>
                                <h1>
                                    Last Item
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
               </section>
           </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: you just forgott the "." point in the second css selector "image-area". Here: main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster:hover > image-area > img {
            transform:scale(1.2,1.2)
        } 
this should be .image-area (image-area is a classname)

Comment: @MarouenMhiri Oh. My . God. I need to take a break. Thank you. P.s. You should answer it!

Comment: np I know that when you spend long time searching for something you overlooked :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just forgotten to put a dot

Like .image-area and problem will be solved:

```
   main#wrap > .page > .group > section.large-poster:hover > .image-area > img {
      transform:scale(1.2,1.2)
   }
```